# Python -> GDAL -Converting raster into CSV but getting only nodata values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, csv

I would like to get a CSV file with x,y coordinates and the correspondent single raster band value: (x, y, value)

This is my code:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

evapotr = gdal.Open('example.tif')

evapotr_trans = gdal.Translate('example.xyz', evapotr)

evapotr_trans_csv = pd.read_csv('example.xyz', sep= " ", header = None)

evapotr_trans_csv.columns = ["x", "y", "ET0"]

evapotr_trans_csv.to_csv('example.csv', index = False)
```

the result is (only no-values):

[image]

I get also to many rows, vectorizing the raster in Qgis
I have an attribute table made of: 8061 rows

While, if I check for the min and max raster value:

```
srcband = evapotranspiration.GetRasterBand(1)

# Get raster statistics
stats = srcband.GetStatistics(True, True)
stats
```

[image]

I get the real min and max.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

You encounter a common issue when working on a georeferenced raster using pandas and numpy. Printing the table displays only the head and tail pixels which are usually in the nodata area shown in green rectangles.

[image]

You will get some pixel values if you use an index range as follows:

```
evapotr_trans_csv[2500:2505]
```